# retrieve chat message in firebase issue in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am using firebase for chat app.when I try to send a message. than message, table got value but not update chat-message table. I refer to this link Here [https://github.com/DevSurya/ChatApp-Swift-And-Firebase].

when I run demo its working fine. Observe method is not calling in my case and collectionview is not refreshing

This is how I write data :

```
private func sendMessageWithProperty(_ property: [String: AnyObject]){
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
        let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
        let toId = user!.id!
        let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let timeStamp = NSNumber.init(value: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        var values: [String : AnyObject] = ["toId":toId as AnyObject, "fromId":fromId as AnyObject, "timeStamp":timeStamp]

        values = values.merged(with: property)

        childRef.updateChildValues(values)

        childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            self.inputTextField.text = nil
            let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(fromId).child(toId)
            let messageId = childRef.key
            userMessageRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])

            let recipentUserMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(toId).child(fromId)
            recipentUserMessageRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
        }
    }
```

This is how I read data

```
 func observeMessage() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let toId = user?.id else {
        return
    }
    let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid).child(toId)
    userMessageRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                return
            }
            let message = Message()
            message.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                self.messages.append(message)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    let indexpath = NSIndexPath.init(item: self.messages.count-1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexpath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

The ObserveMessage() function get automatically called when there is an update in database.but in my case its not get called. I think the problem is with user-messages table: it is not created when I send message.

Comment: do you call reloadData() inside the DispatchQueue.main? Can you check this out? If not, you have to call reloadData() function in the DispatchQueue.main.async block

Comment: but when i send message .in Firebase portal only message table create not user-message table.even i reload it ,it does not have updated message.

Comment: The code you shared shows how you **write** data to the database, not how you read from it. Since the problem seems to be in reading from the database, there's no much we can say until you show us the minimum code that reproduces **that** problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a great explanation of how to best get help when you have code that doesn't do what you expect it to do.